# GAE inviting a user fails You are not authorized to access this application

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine permissions.

I have GAE account and I am trying to invite access to another user

The email is sent and the user pasts the link into Chrome incognito window
The user is asked to login which works but then it says
         You are not authorized to access this application

The user has its own app engines
I can think of nothing else - is there a limit to number who can be invited?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user is logging into the account that you invited (an easy way to do this is by having them just click the link rather than using an Incognito Window). If it still doesn't work, I would suggest you file a bug in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).